# Using an input="submit" field to submit instead of button="" with parsley.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, submit, parsley.js

I currently have an ASP.net page which has one form tag around the entire page. Within that page, I have two forms that are validated with parsley.js when their respective submit button is clicked.
At the moment, the trigger to validate these forms are buttons and I need for them to be input="submit". Does anyone have an idea on how to execute this?

Here's a JS fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/26/

```
<form method='post' id='form'>
<div class="first">
    <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <input type='text' id='phone' name='phone' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <button type="button" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="secon">
    <input type='text' id='thisisrequired' name='thisisrequired' data-parsley-group="second" required />
    <button type="button" id="submit-form2">Submit 2</button>
</div>
```

```
$("#submit-form").on('click', function () {
$('#form').parsley().validate("first");
if ($('#form').parsley().isValid("first")) {

    $('#form').parsley().destroy();
     console.log('valid');
     //$('#form').submit();
} else {
    console.log('not valid');
}});

$("#submit-form2").on('click', function () {
$('#form').parsley().validate("second");
if ($('#form').parsley().isValid("second")) {
    $('#form').parsley().destroy();
    console.log('valid');
} else {
    console.log('not valid');
}});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/29/

Comment: Thanks for replying @Learner ! Yes I thought about that way as well but that doesn't really work for a lot of my forms. Some of them have optional fields and checkboxes and selectboxes so I can't just strip off all the required fields. Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/31/

Comment: @Learner - Hit the reply button too early :p
 
Thanks for replying ! Yes I thought about that way as well but that doesn't really work for a lot of my forms. Some of them have optional fields and checkboxes and selectboxes so I can't just strip off all the required fields. Here's an example - jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/31

Comment: is all the fields are requierd in both divs or some are optional

Comment: @Learner - Some are optional and others are required, so if you remove all the required tags from one form and then try and submit the form it will add required to everything. Even the optional fields. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/34/  just like this

Comment: @Learner Genius! I owe you a tonne. Thanks again and cheers for replying so quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Learner again came to the rescue! Here's his fiddle - [js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/34)

```
<div></div>
```